# Display Specific Amount of Tabs with Viewpager

Tags: android, tabs, android-viewpager

I am using a ViewPager to swipe between 4 tabs.  I'd love to align the tabs where the current tab is in the aligned middle and there is one tab (if available) on far right, and one on far left.

I know you can do some tricky stuff like that with some of the Third party libraries (for example, by Jake Wharton).  But can I have this control with the native ViewPager? (I am also using Support Library v4.)

**At the very least, my question is, can I define how many tabs show up on the screen?  I have 4, and would like 3 at any given time.**

Here is my layout

```
<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical" >


    <TabWidget
        android:id="@android:id/tabs"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="0"
        android:orientation="horizontal" />

    <FrameLayout
        android:id="@android:id/tabcontent"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_weight="0" />

    <android.support.v4.view.ViewPager
        android:id="@+id/viewpager"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_weight="1" />
</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: I am also looking exactly for this

Answer (score 0):

The normal view of a tabbed app has three tabs on the top, and you are allowed to swipe through them. If you have more tabs in your viewpager, you can scroll through as many as you like.

The implementation would be similar to this:

```
public class MainActivity extends FragmentActivity implements ActionBar.TabListener {

    private ViewPager ViewPager;
    private TabsPagerAdapter SectionsPagerAdapter;
    private ActionBar actionBar;

    private String[] tabs = { "Event Details", "Line-up", "Donations", "Concert"};

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

     // Initialisation
        ViewPager = (ViewPager) findViewById(R.id.pager);
        actionBar = getActionBar();
        SectionsPagerAdapter = new TabsPagerAdapter(getSupportFragmentManager());

        ViewPager.setAdapter(SectionsPagerAdapter);
        actionBar.setHomeButtonEnabled(false);
        actionBar.setNavigationMode(ActionBar.NAVIGATION_MODE_TABS); 

     // Adding Tabs
        for (String tab_name : tabs) {
            actionBar.addTab(actionBar.newTab().setText(tab_name).setTabListener(this));
        }

        ViewPager.setOnPageChangeListener(new ViewPager.OnPageChangeListener() {

            @Override
            public void onPageSelected(int position) {
                // on changing the page
                // make respected tab selected
                actionBar.setSelectedNavigationItem(position);
            }

            @Override
            public void onPageScrolled(int arg0, float arg1, int arg2) {
            }

            @Override
            public void onPageScrollStateChanged(int arg0) {
            }
        });
    }

    @Override
    public void onTabReselected(Tab tab, android.app.FragmentTransaction ft) {

    }

    @Override
    public void onTabSelected(Tab tab, android.app.FragmentTransaction ft) {
        ViewPager.setCurrentItem(tab.getPosition());

    }

    @Override
    public void onTabUnselected(Tab tab, android.app.FragmentTransaction ft) {
    }
}
```

Hope this helps :)